nodejs spawn a completely independent terminal window
Before i get into this, I will describe what a successful solution looks like.

Spawn a terminal window containing Ashita-cli.exe
Ashita-cli.exe terminates after starting xiloader.exe
User is able to interact with the terminal window to input a username and password to log into a server.
Terminal window at this point either stays up or closes, I really don't care.
Final Fantasy XI is started by xiloader.exe

So far the issue I'm having is that, regardless of what I do (snippets forthcoming) this process fails to continue after step 2.
Additionally, XILoader supports command line flags to automatically log in with a username and password (this is not ideal for production for obvious reasons) and even using them, the game does not start.
I'm open to hacky solutions if necessary. Ultimately the goal is to get this working, regardless of elegance or lack thereof.
Current snippet that doesn't work
    const proc = spawn(
      'Start-Process',
      [
        '-FilePath',
        `"${join(ASHITA_LOCATION, 'ashita-cli.exe')}"`,
        '-WorkingDirectory',
        `"${ASHITA_LOCATION}"`,
        '-Args',
        `"managed/${scriptName}.ini"`,
        '-Verb',
        'RunAs',
      ], // Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Users\Chris\Magian Launcher\Ashita\Ashita-cli.exe" -WorkingDirectory "C:\Users\Chris\Magian Launcher\Ashita" -Args "managed/default.ini" -Verb RunAs
      {
        shell: 'powershell.exe',
        windowsHide: false,
        detached: true
      }
    )
    proc.unref()

Prior snippet that also didn't work
    spawnSync(
      'Start-Process',
      [
        '-FilePath',
        `"${join(ASHITA_LOCATION, 'ashita-cli.exe')}"`,
        '-WorkingDirectory',
        `"${ASHITA_LOCATION}"`,
        '-Args',
        `managed/${scriptName}.ini`,
        '-Verb',
        'RunAs'
      ], // Start-Process -FilePath C:\Users\Chris\Magian Launcher\Ashita\Ashita-cli.exe -WorkingDirectory C:\Users\Chris\Magian Launcher\Ashita -Args managed/default.ini -Verb RunAs
      {
        shell: 'powershell.exe',
        windowsHide: false
      }
    )

In short:
How do you get a hard (doesn't immediately close on process termination) terminal window that is already running a command using code in node.js?
Windows 11 22631.4169
node 22.8
Tested and failed in Powershell, Powershell ISE, Powershell for Visual Studio 2022 and 2019, VSCode integrated terminal running both Powershell and CMD, and directly running my application using VSCode's IDE features.

spawn is meant to execute the command and that's it. Once the command is done, it is done. Is it the cli or xiloader that requests the user/pass? Or is it that you want to ask the user for it to then launch the processes accordingly?

@Salketer XILoader requests the user/pass. Unfortunately it can't be launched directly in this case as Ashita-CLI has to be able to hook into the processes.

You say that XiLoader accepts credentials in command line arguments, this has to be your way to go but you say it does not work? Have you tested by launching it in command line?? You could have your nodeJS run a terminal and prompt for user/pass, and then start the loader with them. Since you need Ashita-cli, apparently you can put the user/pass in the config file. Now if you don't want them to stay stored, you'd modify the config file, launch the loader and edit out the credentails. I guess...

Whether or not XILoader can launch the game successfully is rather meaningless if the ashita-cli launch process doesn't succeed. Ashita-cli hooks into the loader and game processes to provide modding support, and that's the entire reason I'm building this application in the first place. This is unfortunately an all-or-nothing kind of problem, a partial success is still a total failure.

@Salketer that'd be great if I had access to alter Ashita or XILoaer in any way. Neither of these things are my tools. My options are work with them as they are, or give up.
